# X11 initialization failed

Tags: 12.04

What does this mean

```
** (gnome-shell:4686): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-lauch --autolaunch=de40d0cdda8b10cc42a0ada000000002 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: window manager error: unable to open X display
```

And what do i do to solve it! I can access desktop on **TTY7** and create files and folders but there's no taskbar...

I have tried to install *gnome-shell* and launching it but this was the result!

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the computer from terminal like TTY1 (hit control+alt+F1), try removing the .Xauthority file from your home directory.

```
rm .Xauthority
```

You may need to use sudoin case the permissions are messed up like

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
```

And then restart